# Calculating p-values from a tbl_merge object?

Tags: r, gtsummary

I have been using the R function gtsummary, but have now run into a problem with variables existing in subsets of each other. I have two screening tests that can independently be positive of one another which has created an issue with using by = with tbl_summary. This lead me to create two separate tables and combine them with the tbl_merge function.

However, I would like to calculate p-values for differences between the tests. Is there any way to do this with an object in the table_merge format or to extract information from it and calculate the statistics I need?

Per request, I post a code example from the mtcars database.

## Example code ------------------------------------------------------------

```
data(mtcars)

mtcars_tab <- mtcars %>%
  mutate(
    drat_4 = ifelse(drat >= 4, 1, 0),
    wtp_3 = ifelse(wt >= 3, 1, 0),
    testp = ifelse(drat_4 == 1 | wtp_3 == 1, 1, 0)) %>% 
  select(testp,vs,am)

tab <- 
  tbl_summary(mtcars_tab,
              missing = "no",
              by = testp
              ) %>% 
  add_p

tab
```

[Table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkWvM.png)

What I would like is the table to split into one column where drat_4 is positive and another column where wtp_3 is positive, but I'm having a hard time with this since they are overlapping. Additionally, I would then compare the variables for the positive cases of drat_4 and wtp_3 and add p-values to the table. Sorry if this is confusing. I'll try to clarify!

Would really appreciate your help with this!

Comment: `chisq.test()` might be what you are looking for. Can you please provide data and code to enable us to recreate your issue? Use `dput(your_data)`, copy and paste output into your question in order to share R-Objects with others easily.

Comment: If you post a reproducible example, including data and code we can run on our machine, we can assist. Please also include the code to calculate the difference test.

Comment: Thanks, @DanielD.Sjoberg and Till for the replies! I have added code and clarified the example. Please let me know if I can clarify the issue additionally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the code example solves your problem. You'll need to supplement the code with a proper comparison of the two columns that takes into account that the two groups are not mutually exclusive.

```r
library(gtsummary)
library(tidyverse)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.4.0.9004'

mtcars_tab <- 
  mtcars %>%
  mutate(
    drat_4 = ifelse(drat >= 4, 1, 0),
    wtp_3 = ifelse(wt >= 3, 1, 0)
  ) %>%
  select(drat_4, wtp_3, cyl, mpg)

with(mtcars_tab, table(drat_4, wtp_3))
#>       wtp_3
#> drat_4  0  1
#>      0  6 19
#>      1  6  1


# table among drat_4 test positive
tbl1 <-
  mtcars_tab %>%
  filter(drat_4 == 1) %>%
  tbl_summary(
    missing = "no",
    type = mpg ~ "continuous",
    include = -c(drat_4, wtp_3)
  ) 

# table among wtp_3 test positive
tbl2 <-
  mtcars_tab %>%
  filter(wtp_3 == 1) %>%
  tbl_summary(
    missing = "no",
    type = mpg ~ "continuous",
    include = -c(drat_4, wtp_3)
  ) 

# create a table with the variable and the p.value
tbl_with_pvalue <-
  tibble(
    variable = c("cyl", "mpg"),
    row_type = "label",
    # you'll need to write a proper function here to get the p-values from an approrate test
    p.value = c(0.033, 0.044)
  )


tbl_final <-
  # merge the two tables
  tbl_merge(list(tbl1, tbl2)) %>%
  # add a pvalue comparing the two columns
  modify_table_body(
    ~.x %>%
      dplyr::left_join(
        tbl_with_pvalue,
         by = c("variable", "row_type")
      )
  ) %>%
  # add header for new pvalue column
  modify_header(p.value ~ "**p-value**") %>%
  # add a formatting function for p-value
  modify_fmt_fun(p.value ~ style_pvalue)
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2021-05-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for this solution! I had done something similar myself. Is there any way of extracting sums and percentages from the gtsummary objects to feed into the function for calculating p-values?

Comment: Yep! Here's an example to get to the counts in the first table for the variable cyl `tbl_final %>% purrr::pluck("tbls", 1, "meta_data", "df_stats", 1)`